# to_char number conversion shows null columns

Tags: plsql, obiee

In OBIEE, through a Direct SQL request , I'm trying to concatenate ' USD' to a number. What I'm doing is `SELECT ( TO_CHAR(AMOUNT) || ' USD' ).`
However, this makes all entries in that column show up as blank, with no values at all. 
I've set the column type to varchar.

Comment: And your query provides the appropriate values when run outside of OBIEE?  How does PL/SQL factor into this?

Comment: Yes, it does. In SQLDeveloper, the values show up as intended (e.g. "1500 USD"). I test all my direct queries in SQLDeveloper before creating my OBIEE answers.

Comment: I am on Oracle Business Intelligence 11.1.1.7.160719 and the following works just fine when I set up a new report and allow OBIEE to use default column settings:  WITH Test_Data AS
  (SELECT 123.45 AS Dollar_Amount FROM dual)
 SELECT TO_CHAR(Dollar_Amount) || ' USD' AS USD_Value FROM Test_Data.  Can you try that as a test?

Comment: It works, I've identified a more specific problem , I need to present my results as a pivot table, and that makes the values disappear. It works fine when I set the view to default compund layout.

Comment: Am I to understand that it WASN'T working fine outside of OBIEE?

Comment: @Azerogg so what's the deal? Did you give up on this?

Comment: You know that StackOverflow only works when people actually participate and that includes marking answers as being the correct ones so other users can benefit.

Comment: @Chris, you´re absolutely right. Yes, your answer clarified things for me and I've marked it as correct. I apologise for letting thisdrag on for so long. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you putting your character string into the Measures section of the pivot table? Because that will NOT work in a million years. Measures are numerical and never ever character strings. '200 USD' + '300 USD' as strings makes as much sense as 'blue' + 'dishwasher'. You always aggregate and calculate numerical. The display is a totally diffferent story:

Amount column -> Column Properties -> Data Format -> Override Default Data Format -> Currency.

Long story short: this isn't how OBIEE works and choosing DDRs from the get-go is a fundamentally wrong approach. OBIEE works with models. Not with SQL statements. Why pay for a Ferrari if you turn off the engine and push it manually?